# Using $U$-substitution to Evaluate Trigonometric Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

The question reads as follows:

Evaluate $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^nx\cos x \ dx $ for $ n \geq 0 $.

I know I need to use $u$-substitution, but am stuck on my attempt:

Let:

$$ u = \sin^n x $$
$$ du = n \sin^{n-1}x \ (\cos x) \ dx$$

Are these the correct terms for $u$, $du$?

Comment: I noticed you haven't accepted any answers for any questions you've asked. You can do this by clicking the check mark underneath the up/down vote symbol. It will also increase your rep as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me offer a suggestion on how to solve this expression:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^n(x)\cos(x)dx .$$

Set $u=\sin(x)$, $du=\cos(x)dx$. Then the are actually integrating from $\sin(0)$ to $\sin(\pi/2)$. More specifically,
$$ \int_0^1u^ndu=\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg|_0^1=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

(Note: if anyone could tell me how to make a nice vertical bar to express evaluation from $0$ to $1$, I would appreciate it.)

Comment: You could try either \bigg| or \rvert.  I'm not sure which Latex packages this site uses.

Comment: Already tried \rvert, no luck. Let me try the alternative.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

(1) Try letting $u=\sin (x) $

(2) Don't forget to tack on that extra $dx $ in your expression for $du $

Answer (score 1):

No.  The way you are doing it, the $n-1$ terms of $\sin x$ in $du$ complicate your expression. Use $u=\sin x$ and $du= \cos x\ dx$.  Then you can rewrite the equation as $\int_0^1u^n\ du $ and evaluate.